# Jquery slide. Putting some images into it with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, external

I found a jquery.slide.js script from internet, it is pretty well, but I have to modify it to make it what I exactly want.

First of all, This script renders `<image>` objects inside  `<div id="slides"></div>` and creates a slideshow with them.

I get an ajax data which includes the picture file names inside a folder with this code below:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> Pictures()
{
    List<string> result= new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo files= new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/"));
    List<FileInfo> file_names = new List<FileInfo>();
    FileInfo[] myfiles;
    myfiles = files.GetFiles("*.jpg"); file_names.AddRange(myfiles);
    foreach (FileInfo file in file_names)
    {
        result.Add(file.Name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

//

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/Pictures",
          data: "{}",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function (msg) {
              var indexnum = 0;


              indexnum = 1;
              $.each(msg.d, function (i) {
                  $("<img src='resimler/'" + this + "'></img>").appendTo($(".slidesjs-control"));
                  //THIS .slidejs-control which contains pictures is dynamically created by script, So I am putting my pictures into it
                  //the pictures is firstly put into <div id="slides"> as I mentioned above. Then some divs are appended into "#slides", so the image carrier div becomes ".slidejs-control"
                  indexnum++;
              });
          },
          error: function (msg) { alert("Hata oluştu."); }
      });


//AND IT GOES LIKE THIS TO ADD SOME CLASS TO MY IMAGES WHICH INSIDE .slidejs-control
$(".slidesjs-control", $element).css({
        position: "relative",
        left: 0
      });
      $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        zIndex: 0,
        display: "none",
        webkitBackfaceVisibility: "hidden"
      });
```

//this is my original, non-modified slide div

```
<div id="slides">
      <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
    </div>
```

and this is modified by script version

```
         <div class="container">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; display: block;" id="slides">
              <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 1170px; height: 657.191px;" class="slidesjs-container"><div style="position: relative; left: 0px; width: 1170px; height: 657.191px;" class="slidesjs-control">
    .
    .
    .
    <img slidesjs-index="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 0;" class="slidesjs-slide" src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
    .
    .
    .
    .

             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ".slidejs-control" div is created by following line which stands right before my $.ajax code..

```
$(".slidesjs-container", $element).wrapInner("<div class='slidesjs-control'>", $element).children();
  //AJAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/Resimler",
          data: "{}",
          dataType: "json",
```

The problem is, It doesn't render and put my images -which are dynamically created- into slide show.
But when I add images manually to HTML file, then it puts them into slide show.

I need help here, what may cause that?? I see there are my dynamically added pictures below the manually added ones in developer tools, but they are not modified and putted into slide show.

Thank you!

Comment: Here is the script file for those who wonder : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3l3fy2DeK_1WXp0VmkwUVlBTkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with following way:

instead of ajax, I moved the each loop from .html file to my .aspx file...

But for those who want to use it from .html problem is still here...